# What is the simplest way to timeout in Scala?

Tags: scala, timeout, future

There are many questions on SO that combine Futures with Timeout. To be honest, I haven't completely understood how to use them. But it seems I have stumbled upon a problem where I will have to (or maybe not).

I want to throw a `TimeoutException` if a statement takes more than say 1 minute.To be more clear, currently, this statement tries to get a response from a server but does not throw if the server is not setup. It currently looks like this:

```
//proper import of exceptions
case class ServerException(exception: Throwable) extends Exception(exception)
//Code that instantiates client and post
val response = try {
  client.execute(post)
} catch {
  case e@(_: IOException | _: ClientProtocolException) => throw new ServerException(e)
}
```

To mitigate this problem, I want to introduce a timeout. How do I introduce timeout to this statement such that it throws if no response is got within one minute, else it instantiates `response` and the program continues as it is?

Answer (score 0):

It's not available in scala Futures. You can switch to scalaz Task - it's a bit different abstraction for async/delayed computations. You can read awesome documentation for it here: http://timperrett.com/2014/07/20/scalaz-task-the-missing-documentation/

```
  import java.util.concurrent.Executors
  import scalaz.concurrent.Task
  import scala.concurrent.duration._

  implicit val scheduledThreadPool = 
    Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5)

  def executeRequest(req: Request): Task[Response] = ???

  val withTimeOut: Task[Response] = 
    executeRequest(req).timed(1.minute)
```

**Update**

Btw you can easily transform your Future to Task, for example it Future is coming from 3rd party lib

```
object Future2Task {

  implicit class Transformer[+T](fut: => Future[T]) {
    def toTask(implicit ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext): Task[T] = {
      import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
      import scalaz.syntax.either._
      Task.async {
        register =>
          fut.onComplete {
            case Success(v) => register(v.right)
            case Failure(ex) => register(ex.left)
          }
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: I didn't expect to ever get to read the terms "scalaz" and "awesome documentation" within the same paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Timeouts are usually implemented by having an asynchronous timer act as the timeout signal and completing the future in question whenever it or the timer completes.

I believe Akka has a such a timer, but it's pretty simple to roll your own:

```
object ConcurrencyUtil {

  // creates a Future that will complete after a specified duration
  object Delay {
    def apply(d: Duration): Future[Unit] = {
      val p = Promise[Unit]()
      val t = new Timer
      t.schedule(new TimerTask {
        override def run(): Unit = p.success()
      }, d.toMillis)
      p.future
    }
  }

  implicit class FutureExtensions[T](future: Future[T]) {

    def timeout(timeout: Duration) = Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(
      Delay(timeout).map(_ => throw new TimeoutException()),
      future
    ))
  }
}
```

Now you can compose `timeout` with your future like this:

```
import ConcurrencyUtil._
val f = someTaskReturningAFuture.timeout(1.minute)
```

What is now if the task has not completed within 1 minute, the delay will fire, get mapped to throwing a `TimeoutException` and complete the future `f` as failed.

Note: This does not address cancellation, i.e. the other future, while no longer being listened for will continue to exist and if it's executing something, continue to execute.